# How can I get rid of this error? Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception, picturebox

I have an array of pictureboxes, like this (they all have an image displayed on them, from the designer, from my.resources):

```
Dim imgSourcePic() As PictureBox = {imgAcronym, imgAcrostic, imgAdjective, imgAdverb, imgAlliteration, imgApostrophe, imgClause, imgComma, imgDialogue}
```

and another array of pictureboxes (which don't have an image displayed, yet):

```
 Dim imgDefinitiontoMatch() As PictureBox = {imgDefinition1, imgDefinition2, imgDefinition3, imgDefinition4, imgDefinition5}
```

In the sub NewGame() I have a line of code which is:

```
imgDefinitiontoMatch(intX).Image = imgSourcePic(intRandomNumber).Image
```

But, whenever it executes this line of code I get this error:

[image]

I debugged it and saw that the pictureboxes, in the array, are displaying the Image property as 'Nothing'.

[image]

How else can I assign an image to the pictureboxes in imgSourcePic() that'll work?

I have tried creating variables for all of the images, such as:

```
Dim picAcronym As Image = My.Resources.Acronymn_definition
...
```

But still doesn't achieve anything.

I hope this isn't a duplicate, but I have been trying to figure it out all day and can't seem to make
it work :(

Many thanks and, as always, hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the Load() Event of the Form, which I see you already have in your code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private PBs() As PictureBox

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PBs = {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3}

        ' ... more code ...

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Sorry late reply - was at work. I have tried both ways, but still get the error. Do I need to assign the images to the pictureboxes in the code as well, such as imgAcronym.image = My.resources.acronym_definition? I mean, they are already displayed on the pictureboxes on the designer, but this isn't working. Many thanks.

Comment: If you're still getting errors then either you didn't implement the suggested changes correctly, or you have an issue somewhere else due to your code.  Show us more actual code, not screenshots.

Comment: You're right, I had an issue elsewhere. Thank-you for helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

You're populating those arrays before `InitializeComponent()` runs, so all of the variables are still `Nothing`.

You need to assign the array in `Sub New()`, after `InitializeComponent()` (which creates the actual `PictureBox`es)